# outer join in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, join

i have 3 table in sqlServer As follows:

Cost_Types

```
Id   COST_NAME
-------------
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E
6      F
7      Z
```

and Request Table

```
Id   No
----------
1     100
2     200
3     300
```

and Cost_Request (= clearance_cost)

```
RequestId     CostId   Amount
-------------------------------
1               2       200
1               3       400
```

i want Get this Result

```
RequestId     CostId   Amount
    -------------------------------
    1               2       200
    1               3       400
    1               1        0
    1               4        0
    1               5        0
    1               6        0
```

i write this code

```
var context = new CLEARANCEEntities();
        var items = (from c in context.COST_TYPES
                     join t in context.CLEARANCE_COST
                         on c.COST_ID equals t.COST_ID into outer
                     from t in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where t. RequestId==1
                     select new
                          {
                            c.COST_ID,
                            c.COST_NAME, I = ((t == null) ? 0 : t.COST_AMOUNT)
                          }).ToList();
```

this code just return this

```
    RequestId     CostId   Amount
    -------------------------------
    1               2       200
    1               3       400
```

and i want if change Query As follows:

```
var context = new CLEARANCEEntities();
            var items = (from c in context.COST_TYPES
                         join t in context.CLEARANCE_COST
                             on c.COST_ID equals t.COST_ID into outer
                         from t in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where t.RequestId==2               
                         select new
                                    {
                                        c.COST_ID,
                                        c.COST_NAME, I = ((t == null) ? 0 : t.COST_AMOUNT)
                                    }).ToList();
```

return this data

```
 RequestId     CostId   Amount
    -------------------------------
    2               1      0
    2               2      0
    2               3      0
    2               4      0
    2               5      0
    2               6      0
```

please help me. thanks all

Comment: @user1166147: i have 3 table Request and Cost Type and CostRequest, Clearance_Cost is CostRequest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the GroupJoin->SelectMany->DefaultIfEmpty technique of LEFT JOIN'ing is popular... but I think that the SelectMany->NavigationPropertyJoin->DefaultIfEmpty technique is much clearer.

```
var query =
  from c in context.CostTypes
  from xr in c.CostRequests
    .Where(xrRecord => xrRecord.RequestId == 1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new {
    CostType = c,
    Amount = xr == null ? 0 : xr.Amount
  }
```

Comment: how does the `from xr in c.costRequests` work ? how come c.costrequests is an IEnumerable? could you point me to some resources where this technique is described in more detail / with more examples ?

Comment: each "from" after the first is translated into SelectMany.  CostTYpe.CostRequests is a navigation property.  It is IEnumerable because each CostType has many CostRequests.

Comment: @DavidB: thanks for help me. but i have new problem , if i want use this Query for 3 or 4 table i get error, please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Completely modifying answer after coming to different understanding of question:

***NEW ANSWER***

*Try moving your WHERE condition to JOIN clause.*

You are not doing an inner join - so the condition on the join is okay here and won't eliminate your nulls when you have matches.  But if you put t.RequestId==whatever in your where clause you just filtered them out.

***OLD ANSWER -INCORRECT- ANSWERED WRONG QUESTION***
It looks like CostId and RequestId have gotten swapped on the insert into the Cost_Request table, so you are doing a left join and joining  c.COST_ID equals t.COST_ID but t.COST_ID really contains RequestId in the actual data in the table. This would fully explain the result sets you are seeing. **To test this theory, change your join to**

```
c.COST_ID equals t.REQUEST_ID
```

and see if you get the results you expect.
Although without seeing your entity models this is hard because the query provided does not match the names in the tables provided and I'm doing some guessing.

Comment: I understand that COST_ID equals t.COST_ID is the intention - It looks like the data in the tables may have gotten messed up - try the suggested test above and see what results you get.  I am not saying that you would leave it that way - just try it to see if bad data is your issue.

Comment: I finally get what you are trying to ask - You are trying to do the equivalent of a right join -when you get records meeting criteria, it doesn't get nulls, but when you get 0 matches you do.  Try moving your WHERE condition to JOIN clause. As @Joanna said, you are filtering out rows with your where. PLEASE clean up your posts to get better answers. This is really messy. Particularly if your select and your expected results make it look like you are selecting an Id from one table and displaying it with the name of an id from another table (Pushed me down the the Cost_id == requestId wormhole).

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that you are filtering out all the other rows with the `where t == 1` statement. I'm not sure what `t` is at that stage that you can filter on it - it seems to correspond to clearence_cost.request_id.

Have you tried the query without the `where` clause ?

Also, it's very confusing what you have in the select statement:

```
 select new
         {
            c.COST_ID,
            c.COST_NAME, 
            I = ((t == null) ? 0 : t.COST_AMOUNT)
          }
```

Looking at the 'expected' result set it seems that c.Cost_id == requestId ?, c.CostName == cost_id ? What is Cost_name at all ?

And honestly, if you want an answer to this problem you have to invest some time and tidy up the mess in your post first. You can't expect people to guess why the names are different and magically know what you meant.

Comment: i use where clause for load or fill just for one request.