# How to perform left join in linq having multiple table joins

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have the following `LinQ` query:

```
List<string> emails = (from u in context.User
                            join h in context.Hero
                            on u.UserID equals h.UserID
                            join hc in context.HeroCategory
                            on h.HeroID equals hc.HeroID
                            where
                            (hc.QuestionCategoryID == 1
                            && h.IsHeroAdmin) || h.IsHeroSuperAdmin
                            select u.EmailAddress).ToList<string>();
```

I am trying to get list of emails if a hero belongs to a certain category and if he is a admin or if the hero is super admin.

When I try to write the above query in `sql` using left join, I am getting the correct result:

```
SELECT 
    U.EmailAddress
FROM USERS U LEFT JOIN
    Heroes H ON (U.UserID=H.UserID) LEFT JOIN
    HeroCategory HC ON (H.HeroID=HC.HeroID)
WHERE (HC.QuestionCategoryID=1 AND H.IsHeroAdmin=1)
   OR H.IsHeroSuperAdmin=1
```

Basically I want to know to perform a simple left join in the above mentioned linq query.

Comment: Check out [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920653/multiple-tables-left-join-using-linq).  It should provide you with your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1971086/2039359 describes how to do multiple left joins

Comment: Left join is not the problem - in that SQL the WHERE negates the left.   You are missing into group LINQ syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but you should take care of nulls in where clause, because if you are doing `left join` then why you are filtering and not consider nulls?:

```
List<string> emails = (from u in context.User
                       join h in context.Hero on u.UserID equals h.UserID into hleft
                       from hl in hleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join hc in context.HeroCategory on hl.HeroID equals hc.HeroID into hcleft
                       from hcl in hcleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where
                       (hcl.QuestionCategoryID == 1
                       && hl.IsHeroAdmin) || hl.IsHeroSuperAdmin
                       select u.EmailAddress).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are testing the values of Heroes in your `WHERE` clause, you've effectively turned your `LEFT JOIN` on Heroes into an `INNER JOIN`.  The only `LEFT JOIN` needed is the one on `HeroCategory`, and then only if the Hero isn't a superadmin (Again, because you test the value of `HeroCategory`'s `QuestionCategoryId` if they aren't a `SuperAdmin`).

You need to fix your logic first, but here's the equivalent, assuming Users to Heros is a one to many relationship, and `HeroCategories` is one to many:

```
var emails=context.Users
  .Where(u=>u.Heros.Any(h=>
      (h.IsHeroAdmin==1 && h.HeroCategories.Any(hc=>hc.QuestionCategoryID==1))
          || u.Heros.Any(h=>h.IsHeroSuperAdmin==1)))
  .Select(u=>u.EmailAddress)
  .ToList();
```

If Users to Heros is a 1:1 relationship, then it would be like this:

```
var emails=context.Users
  .Where(u=>(u.Heros.IsHeroAdmin==1 && h.Heros.HeroCategories.Any(hc=>hc.QuestionCategoryID==1)) || u.Heros.IsHeroSuperAdmin==1)
  .Select(u=>u.EmailAddress)
  .ToList();
```